# Specifying multiple conditions in xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to select all the tags with `<td class='blob-code blob-code-addition'> and <td class='blob-code blob-code-deletion'>` . So I am trying to include `or` condition here between the two predicates. It does not work. However, if I include only one of the two classes it works . What is the problem here? Something is wrong with the syntax.

```
By getChanges = By.xpath("//td[@class='blob-code blob-code-addition'] or  //td[@class='blob-code blob-code-deletion']");
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to specify that like the following:

```
//td[contains(@class,'deletion') or contains(@class,'addition')]
```

or

```
//td[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')]
```

**If you want to do a `tag` independent search then you can simply use**

```
//*[contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code blob-code-deletion')]
```

From your answer it looks like you are trying to concatenate two different `xpath`s

**However, `contians()` is not mandatory here. You also can do without this**

```
//*[(@class='blob-code blob-code-addition') or (@class='blob-code blob-code-deletion')]
```

Comment: So we cannot use "or" directly? It has to go with contains?

Comment: @Zack you can but not starting with `//`. I am using `or` as well. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes. But in all the three solutions you have used "contains". It worked. I was just curious why it did not work without contains.

Answer (score 3):

what works for me is below expression **using "|" character** inside my expression-

By element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@clas='xyz'] | //button[@clas='abc']"))

I used above expression for JAVA + Selenium + Maven project

Answer (score 0):

using pom: 
`@FindBy(xpath ="//span[contains(@class,'vui-menuitem-label-text') and normalize-space(.) = 'Clone']")`

Answer (score 0):

To select all the tags with:

- `<td class="blob-code blob-code-addition">`
- `<td class="blob-code blob-code-deletion">`

You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* through `class` attribute with *or* clause:

  ```
  //td[@class='blob-code blob-code-addition' or @class='blob-code blob-code-deletion']
  ```
- Using *xpath* through single `class` attribute with *or* clause:

  ```
  //td[contains(@class,'blob-code-addition') or contains(@class,'blob-code-deletion')]
  ```
- Using *xpath* through partial `class` attribute with *or* clause:

  ```
  //td[contains(@class,'addition') or contains(@class,'deletion')]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

For writing Multiple Xpath in one element selenium

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="any-content"]//p|//h3|//figure')
```

You can write many tags by using "|" modulo.