# Official locator strategies for the webdriver

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, chromium, chrome-web-driver

In the [official W3C webdriver documentation](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#locator-strategies), it's clearly stated that the location strategies are:

```
State                       Keyword
-----------------------------------------------
CSS selector                "css selector"
Link text selector          "link text"
Partial link text selector  "partial link text"
Tag name                    "tag name"
XPath selector              "xpath"
```

However, [Selenium's wire protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) allowed:

```
class name
css selector
id
name
link text
partial link text
tag name
xpath
```

In *theory*, Selenium's documentation is obsolete and the "real" story is in the new specification document. However...

I ran some tests on the latest Chrome's own Webdriver, and I can confirm that `name` and `class name` both work; however, they are not in the specifications.

I remember reading on a Chromium issue that they would only ever implement the official Webdriver specifications.

Now: I *know* the generic answer, where "specifications are not always followed 100%", etc. However, I'd like to know:

- Can you find the code in Chromium that implements this? (a link would be most welcome)
- Have there been discussions about these in the Chromium mailing list?
- Are the "unofficial" commands (which are documented in the "old" Selenium specifications file) likely to stay? Where is the evidence for it?

Comment: Chrome driver code is somewhere inside these links on the page - https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/contributing. Some more info that will be helpful in explaining this discrepancy -- https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1041.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you saw it right.

As per the current *WebDriver - W3C Candidate Recommendation* the [*Locator Strategies*](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#locator-strategies) enlisted are as follows:

- *"css selector"*: CSS selector
- *"link text"*: Link text selector
- *"partial link text"*: Partial link text selector
- *"tag name"*: Tag name
- *"xpath"*: XPath selector

Snapshot:

[image: Locator Strategies]

However, the [*JsonWireProtocol*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#post-sessionsessionidelementidelement) was once used to support the *Locator Strategies* enlisted below, but currently the documentation clearly states its *Status* as *obsolete*:

- *class name*: Returns an element whose class name contains the search value; compound class names are not permitted.
- *css selector*: Returns an element matching a CSS selector.
- *id*: Returns an element whose ID attribute matches the search value.
- *name*: Returns an element whose NAME attribute matches the search value.
- *link text*: Returns an anchor element whose visible text matches the search value.
- *partial link text*: Returns an anchor element whose visible text partially matches the search value.
- *tag name*: Returns an element whose tag name matches the search value.
- *xpath*: Returns an element matching an XPath expression. The provided XPath expression must be applied to the server "as is"; if the expression is not relative to the element root, the server should not modify it. Consequently, an XPath query may return elements not contained in the root element's subtree.

Snapshot:

[image: Locator Strategies]

The change was propagated through the respective *client*-specific bindings. For the *Selenium-Java* clients here is the [client code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/13d8f8be751001d44df8e5f1797518f4fb4dec6b/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/W3CHttpCommandCodec.java#L187) where we have the switch case working for the users:

```html
        switch (using) {
          case "class name":
            toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
            toReturn.put("value", "." + cssEscape(value));
            break;

          case "id":
            toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
            toReturn.put("value", "#" + cssEscape(value));
            break;

          case "link text":
            // Do nothing
            break;

          case "name":
            toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
            toReturn.put("value", "*[name='" + value + "']");
            break;

          case "partial link text":
            // Do nothing
            break;

          case "tag name":
            toReturn.put("using", "css selector");
            toReturn.put("value", cssEscape(value));
            break;

          case "xpath":
            // Do nothing
            break;
        }
        return toReturn;
```

Snapshot:

[image: JAVA_classname_id_name_tagname]

Now, your question must be why this change in the *W3C specification* and in the *clients*. As per [#1042](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1042) the *answer* from the *WebDriver Contributors* was pretty straight as:

> This keeps the specification simple as these can be implemented using the CSS selector, which maps down to querySelector/querySelectorAll.

Comment: While comparing getElementById and querySelector, i found that getElementById is fast. I really don't understand Why id locator is obsolete. Please check: https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector