# Python/Selenium find elements with specific tags, classes, firstchild by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I need to extract elements of an HTML page, linearly (keeping true to the order of appearance) in a list. Picking elements individually - in separate lists - looks like so:

```
date_select = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='dayHeader']//h5")
time_select = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='col0Item']")
class_select = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='col1Item']")
duration_select = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='col4Item']")
```

I've managed to get to the following:

```
output = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, 'dayHeader') or contains(@class, 'col0Item') or contains(@class, 'col1Item') or contains(@class, 'col4Item')]')
```

But the problem is that this line has a wildcard for the tags and also doesn't take into account the firstchild for date_select. So "output" saves a lot of unwanted elements.

How can I get as precise to output all date/time/class/duration linearly, into one line?

Comment: What's the url page or the html file?

Comment: The page isn't accessible without a login but since it was a syntax problem I didn't feel necessary to post the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually managed to figure one way out:

```
output = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class,'dayHeader')]//h5|//span[contains(@class,'col0Item') or contains(@class,'col1Item') or contains(@class,'col4Item')]")
```

The solution was explained on [Specifying multiple conditions in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529577/specifying-multiple-conditions-in-xpath).
Explanation of `|` ("pipe" operator) on [Pipe character in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988665/pipe-character-in-python)